# Вставка html кода с другого сайта

Tags: ajax, html, javascript

У меня есть сайт на домене a.ru, второй на домене b.ru. У меня есть url `http://a.ru/some/request`, по которому сайт a.ru возвращает html-код. Каким образом запросить этот код с сайта b.ru?

Answer (score 1):

Здесь нужно использовать Ajax. Из-за "Защиты от пиратства" вам нужно писать скрипты `b.ru`, например, на `PHP` и обращаться к ним... А если вам просто отобразить, то можно и использовать `<ifarme>`.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать CURL.

Answer (score 0):

А чем не подходит

`file_get_contents(url)`

Функция запрашивает HTML-код страницы и возвращает его.